# Composition of a bounded Lipschitz continuous function with a Sobolev function

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ supposed convex with sufficiently smooth boundary. Let $T$ be a compactly supported Lipschitz continuous function that is extended to the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$ with zero. Let $\varphi \in H^1(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^2)$.
Is $T \circ \varphi \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$? If yes, is it possible to relate its $L^{\infty}$-norm with the one of $T$?
I do thank you very much. Best wishes.

Comment: Of course, the (essential) range of $T\circ \phi$ is a subset of the range of $T$.

Comment: Many thanks so it is correct to write that $\|T \circ \varphi\|_{L^{\infty}{\Omega}} \leq \|T\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}$? My doubt was that we know $T \circ \varphi \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ but as we work in two dimensions we have only the Sobolev injection into $L^q(\Omega)$ $\forall q \in [1,+\infty[$.

Comment: Since $T$ is bounded everywhere (not just a.e.), the same is true for $T \circ \varphi$. If only this map is measurable (and it is), then by definition it belongs to $L^\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is clear. Best wishes.